# Making multi-line plots in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, scale-color-manual

I would like to compile some data into a `ggplot()` line plot of different colors.

It's rainfall in various places over 100 days, and the data is quite different between locations which is giving me fits.

I've tried using different suggestions from this forum and they don't seem to be working well for this data. Sample data:

```
Time        Location1   Location2           Location3
0           48          99.2966479761526    2
1           51          98.7287820735946    4
2           58          98.4803262236528    4.82842712474619
3           43          97.8941490454599    5.46410161513775
4           47          96.6091435402632    6
5           47          95.207282404881     6.47213595499958
6           41          94.8696538619697    6.89897948556636
7           34          94.6514389757067    7.29150262212918
8           40          93.7297335476615    7.65685424949238
9           57          93.2440731907263    8
```

My code thus far is

```r
ggplot(Rain) + 
 geom_line(aes(x=Time,y=Location1,col="red")) +  
 geom_line(aes(x=Time,y=Location2,col="blue")) + 
 geom_line(aes(x=Time,y=Location3,col="green")) + 
 scale_color_manual(labels = c("Location 1","Location 2","Location 3"),
                    values = c("red","blue","green")) +
 xlab("Time (Days)") + ylab("Rainfall (Inches)") + labs(color="Locations") + 
 ggtitle("Rainfall Over 100 Days In Three Locations")
```

So far it gives me everything that I want but for some reason the colors are wrong when I plot it, i.e. it plots location 1 in green while I told it red in my first `geom_line`.

Comment: You can use ```dput(head(df, 20))``` to share a snippet of your data. ```df```  would be your ```data.frame```.

Comment: Can you also please add what you have so far vs the expected output?

Comment: Of course. my code thus far is    >ggplot(Rain) + geom_line(aes(x=Time,y=Location1,col="red")) + geom_line(aes(x=Time,y=Location2,col="blue")) + geom_line(aes(x=Time,y=Location3,col="green")) + xlab("Time (Days)") + ylab("Rainfall (Inches)") + ggtitle("Rainfall Over 100 Days In Three Locations") +labs(color="Locations")+scale_color_manual(labels=c("Location 1","Location 2","Location 3"),values = c("red","blue","green"))     So far it gives me everything I want but for some reason the colors are wrong when I plot it i.e. it plots location 1 in green while I told it red in my first geom_line

Comment: You can [edit] the post to add your code so it's easier to read it. You need your data to be in a long format, which is what ggplot expects, so you can assign a variable to the color. There are a lot of posts already on SO that deal with that

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

```r
df_long <- gather(data = df1, Place, Rain, -Time)

ggplot(df_long) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Time, y=Rain, color=Place))
```

[image]

***Data:***

```r
df1 <- read.table(text="Time        Location1   Location2           Location3
                        0           48          99.2966479761526    2
                        1           51          98.7287820735946    4
                        2           58          98.4803262236528    4.82842712474619
                        3           43          97.8941490454599    5.46410161513775
                        4           47          96.6091435402632    6
                        5           47          95.207282404881     6.47213595499958
                        6           41          94.8696538619697    6.89897948556636
                        7           34          94.6514389757067    7.29150262212918
                        8           40          93.7297335476615    7.65685424949238
                        9           57          93.2440731907263    8", 
                  header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```